# #IfWinActive / #ifWinExist not working as expected in ahk

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
^!c::MsgBox You pressed Control+Alt+C in Notepad.
#IfWinActive ahk_class WordPadClass
^!c::MsgBox You pressed Control+Alt+C in WordPad.
#IfWinActive
^!c::MsgBox You pressed Control+Alt+C in a window other than Notepad/WordPad.
```

works as expected , however when i try the below code... the message box does not appear

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
!c::MsgBox You pressed Alt+C in Notepad.
#IfWinActive ahk_class WordPadClass
^!c::MsgBox You pressed Control+Alt+C in WordPad.
#IfWinActive
^!c::MsgBox You pressed Control+Alt+C in a window other than Notepad/WordPad.
```

i just dont know why it does not work

Comment: Works as expected for me. Which part exactly isn't working for you? Is that all your code or is there something else as well?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using this in a virtual desktop environment? I'm able to replicate this problem from Citrix Desktop.